# IBM blockchain platform - "Failed to import smart contract package: Source and destination must not be the same."

Tags: ibm-blockchain

I upgraded the IBM blockchain platform to 1.0.16

Now I run into an blocking issue.
When I try and import an existing package I receive the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to import smart contract package: Error: Source and destination must not be the same.
```

I still can create a new project and package it, but I cannot import it.

Moreover, it seems that the engine is always running: I have the blue clock symbol on the activity bar.

Comment: You might want to try raising an issue here https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension/issue and provide as much detail as you can, including platform